# How to show that $\frac {1}{2^n} \lt \frac {1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $\frac {1}{2^n} \lt \frac {1}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$? I tried using mathematical induction. The base case is evidently true since $$\frac {1}{2} \lt 1$$ Assuming that the proposition holds for some $k \ge 1$ such that $k \in \mathbb N$, then we need to show that $$\frac {1}{2^{k+1}} \lt \frac {1}{k+1}$$ This is where I don't know how to proceed. All I could achieve was $$\frac {1}{2^{k+1}} \lt \frac {1}{2} \cdot \frac {1}{2^{k}} \lt \frac {1}{2^{k}} \lt \frac {1}{k}$$

Comment: If you don't forget the factor $\frac12$ and write $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2^k} < \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{k},$$ you will probably get to the end.

Comment: You can also just prove that $2^n>n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: use $2^n\geq 2n>n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {1}{2^{k+1}} = \frac {1}{2*2^{k}} \lt \frac {1}{2k} \leq \frac {1}{k+1}$

Comment: The leftmost strict inequality does not hold. It's an equality.

Comment: Yea but again the right-most has an issue. Take $k=1$, we have an equality. See my hint above.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{2^n}\leq \dfrac{1}{2n}<\dfrac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 1):

We shall show that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$, $n<2^n$. Let $n=1$, then the result is trivial. Now suppose we have already proven that $n<2^n$ for $n\ge1$. Then we have

$$2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^{n}>2\cdot n \ge n+1$$

Since $n\ge1$, so we have $1/2^n<1/n$ as desired.